# cannot copy paste with keyboard shortcuts in a application

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, desktop

i have the following problem. I am working on an application which is a desktop app that includes a web browser and loads aspx pages inside it. Well a very messy structure, i dont know why they have done it like that. Anyway, the problem is keyboard shortcuts like ctrl-c, ctrl-v; ctrl-f are not working there. And even the mouse cursor cannot be placed inside words in textboxs. 
Where do you think the problem might be? Is something app-specific or something that cannot be fixed?

Comment: Can you at least highlight text within the app's browser and right-click to copy it, or is even that functionality not?